# Logic error - checking if one word can be formed from another

Tags: python

Code works in most cases, but gives wrong answer when a word with more than one character that is the same...

```
first = input('Enter first word: ')

second = input('Enter second word: ')

isIn = 0

for i in first:
    for j in second:
        if i == j:
            isIn += 1
            break


if isIn == len(first):
    print('Word one can be formed from word two')

else:
    print('Word one can\'t be formed from word two')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "forming a word from a another"? I don't even know which output you'd expect for "meet" and "meat". Can you form "meet" from "meat"? Do you try to find anagrams?

Comment: Perhaps use set(first) and set(second) to create a set of unique characters in each word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `e` in `meat` is getting counted twice.

```
from collections import Counter

first_word = "meet"
second_word = "meat"

first_counter = Counter(first_word)
second_counter = Counter(second_word)

for key, value in first_counter.items():
    if second_counter[key] != value:
        print(f"You cannot construct \"{first_word}\" from \"{second_word}\"")
        break
else:
    print(f"You can construct \"{first_word}\" from \"{second_word}\"")
```

Comment: @LydiavanDyke The thing is, I'm almost certain the OP isn't interested in determining whether two words are anagrams. They were asking if one word can be formed from the exact number of letters from another. This does not mean that all letters in the second word need to be taken into account. For example, I can construct the word "loot" from the word "tools". They aren't anagrams, but "tools" contains all the letters I need for "loot". To be precise, the count of all the letters of the first word, which also appear in the second, is the same. At least that's how I interpreted it.

Comment: Ah, now is see it. Well, I withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to check if two words are anagrams of each other is to sort the strings first, so that they will be the same if they contain the same letters. This will handle the case that you've encountered where one word contains multiple letters that is required in the second or visa versa.

```py
sorted(first) == sorted(second)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if each letter in `first` can be found in `second`. The problem is that if there is at least 1 letter in `second`, no matter how many of that letter is found in `first`, `isIn` will always be incremented.
You need find a way to keep count of how many of one letters is found in both variables and develop a logic around that.

There are multiple approaches possible, you may look into `COUNT()` and `SORTED()` among other functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
def formed_by(w1, w2):
    return bool(sorted(w1)==sorted(w2))
```

It returns True if w1 is formed by w2 and vice versa, else it returns False.